# Verifying zendesk webhook authenticity in c#

Tags: c#, webhooks, zendesk

I am trying to verify the webhook signature to validate webhook signature

below is my code for c# but it is not working

```
string json = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
string signature = Request.Headers["x-zendesk-webhook-signature"];
string timestamp = Request.Headers["x-zendesk-webhook-signature-timestamp"];
            
// Signing secret from webhook itself 
string SIGNING_SECRET = "Secret key";
            
_logger.LogDebug("Zendesk signature: " + signature);
_logger.LogDebug("Zendesk timestamp: " + timestamp);
_logger.LogDebug("Zendesk body: " + json);
var b1 = timestamp + json;
string newSignature = "";

using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SIGNING_SECRET)))
{
    var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(b1));
    newSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}

return signature.Equals(newSignature, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I am following below document for reference but it is in node

https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/event-connectors/webhooks/verifying/#verifying-the-signature

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: The signature i am getting from zendesk response i.e., Request.Headers["x-zendesk-webhook-signature"] and the signature generated from this code i.e., newSignature are different.